# AWS IAM: cognito-idp:LookupDomain

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito, amazon-iam

I'm trying to create a user pool, but I'm stuck when trying to verify that a Cognito domain name exists. I get this error:
perform: cognito-idp:LookupDomain on resource: * because no identity-based policy allows the cognito-idp:LookupDomain action

However, I'm not sure how to allow that, seeing as LookupDomain is not listed here: https://awscli.amazonaws.com/v2/documentation/api/latest/reference/cognito-idp/index.html

Comment: What permissions does the principal that's trying to do this have?

Answer (score 0):

Interestingly, as of the time of writing (Nov 14, 2023), the `cognito-idp:LookupDomain` seems to be an undocumented permission.

You can grant this permission using the IAM policy editor but you it's not documented, or available in the IAM visual policy editor. And even the policy validator identifies this as an error.

Despite the validation error, once you add `cognito-idp:LookupDomain` as an allowed action to your policy, the principal the policy applies to should get access to perform the domain lookups.